# Can a lookup be done by fbid? (Instagram API)?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I was wondering if it is possible to look up a user using the fbid that gets shown when using the Instagram API to look up a user. For example, I used the following URL to look up the official Instagram account:

```
https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1
```

This URL returns a JSON object and within that there is a fbid key like so:

```
"fbid" : "17841400039600391"
```

Is there anything useful that can be done with this fbid such as looking up a user?

Comment: No there is not.

Comment: you could try https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=>>fbid<<